# how the image should be in the area between the two buttons?

Tags: android

hiii...i am able to show image from images urls, actually images urls was stored in a array string and i had display images using

```
URL aURL = new URL(imagePath);
URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
conn.connect();
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
bis.close();
is.close();

imageLoader.setImageBitmap(bm);

imageLoader.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

**now i want to add two button which will be left and right of image means image will be between two button....my main.xml is**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageLoader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Button>
    <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

how to do it i am eagerly waiting for responces...thanks for all responces in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `RelativeLayout` to achieve this, something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button android:id="@+id/back" android:text="Back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/next" android:text="Next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageLoader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/next"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/back" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

to have the `Buttons` vertically centered in the view, so they would lye on the left and the right side of the wrapped image, you should change the `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` in their declaration to `android:layout_centerVertical="true"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button android:id="@+id/back" android:text="Back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/next" android:text="Next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageLoader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/next"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/back" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @rekazeru first of all thanks for so fast responce...when i running this code buttons are left and right  but it is on the top of layout and image are below from button actually i want buttons should be in left and right of image and also between the image i think i m now able to explain my problem...

Comment: change the `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` to `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` in both `Button` declarations, and they will be displayed in the desired place.

Answer (score 0):

Try horizonal orientation for the layout that should be good enough. android:orientation="vertical">  Instead use horizontal.  Also change the sequence in layout to button, image, button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageLoader"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageLoader"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dip">
</Button>
<Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageLoader"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dip">
</Button>
```

Adjust the top value as per ur requirement...Hope it helps u...